# How to Check Each Row of GridView and Display Message on Error?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have an ASPX gridview with a checkbox in the first column and a comment textbox in the last column. I'd like to require users to leave a comment if they uncheck the checkbox.

Originally, I thought that I could use a For Each on the VB-side and push a message through, alerting the user that they forgot to include a comment. From looking around, it looks like MsgBox and MessageBox are unusable in this context. One other option I saw mentioned using Response.Write and scripting in some java, but I couldn't get that to work. Other users have mentioned that using Response.Write like this could cause issues if there's ever an error.

Is there any way to do this? Again, I'd like to check each row, and if the checkbox is unchecked, make sure that there's something in the comment textbox. I'm intermediate in my VB knowledge, but this is my first time messing with ASP.net. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like something you would do in JavaScript. A gridview just renders as a table in the browser to it is easy to traverse the DOM to check each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After failing to find an easy way to push a message to the user, I decided to make use of a button that I was already using on the front end to send my updates.

```
<asp:Button ID="ApproveList" 
    runat="server" 
    style="width:200px;" 
    Text="Approve List" 
    CausesValidation="true"
    OnClick="UpdateSelectedRecords_Click"
    OnClientClick="return confirm('YOUR RECORDS WILL NOT BE APPROVED UNLESS ALL UNAPPROVED RECORDS HAVE A COMMENT. Are you sure you want to approve these records?');"/>
```

When the user hits the button and confirms that they'd like to proceed, it runs the UpdateSelectedRecords_Click sub on the VB-side. The first part of that sub checks each row for my conditions, and if it finds any issues, it just ends the sub.

```
' Verify that every unchecked row has a comment, else fail
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridUnapprovedRecords.Rows
    cb = CType(row.FindControl("CheckBox1"),CheckBox)
    strComment = row.FindControl("Comment")
    If Not cb.Checked Then
        If strComment.Text Is Nothing Or Len(strComment.Text) = 0 Then
            intErrors = intErrors + 1
        End If
    End If
Next

' If no unchecked boxes without comments, run updates
If intErrors = 0 Then
    ...
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I'm sure there are more eligant options, but this gets the job done.